# How to import specific PortNumber constructor

Tags: haskell

Simple question.

This compiles:

```
module Example where

import Network

port :: PortID
port = PortNumber 3001
```

And this does not:

```
module Example where

import Network (PortID, PortNumber)

port :: PortID
port = PortNumber 3001
```

GHC says:

```
Example.hs:6:8: Not in scope: data constructor `PortNumber'
```

Why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It has to be

```
import Network (PortID(PortNumber))
```

as `PortNumber` seems to be a constructor of `PortID`. The other import simply imports all of `Network` and hence `PortNumber` is found.

Comment: You can import all of the constructors of a data-type with e.g. `import Network (PortID(..))`.